# debug angular application errors that are not well informative

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, exception, error-handling

I have started one of my old projects.
Updated all dependencies and angular to the latest version.

Now, when I launch the project - I get an error:

```
main.ts:12 Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AuthState: (?, ?).
    at getUndecoratedInjectableFactory (core.js:17158)
    at injectableDefOrInjectorDefFactory (core.js:17142)
    at providerToFactory (core.js:17210)
    at providerToRecord (core.js:17192)
    at R3Injector.processProvider (core.js:17008)
    at core.js:16969
    at core.js:1400
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at deepForEach (core.js:1400)
    at R3Injector.processInjectorType (core.js:16965)
```

My question is - How to debug such kind of errors in Angular?

**main.ts** file, 11 and 12 lines are:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

it is an application-scope exception handler.

So, anything I know from the error, that something is wrong with AuthState - but what exactly, where exactly and why - no information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, all NGXS `@State()` classes now should be prefixed with the `@Injectable()` decorator.

https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/ivy-migration-guide